# Toolbox theme using printif statement - help needed understanding code block

Tags: theme-development, themes

I want to make edits to the following so that I can display the author and date but without those being links to searches 'by date' and 'by author'. The site I'm building will only have one author and I want to lock down the searches users can do.

Code as follows:

```
        <?php
            printf( __( '<span class="sep">Posted on </span><a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%2$s" pubdate>%3$s</time></a> <span class="sep"> by </span> <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%4$s" title="%5$s">%6$s</a></span>', 'toolbox' ),
                get_permalink(),
                get_the_date( 'c' ),
                get_the_date(),
                get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ),
                sprintf( esc_attr__( 'View all posts by %s', 'toolbox' ), get_the_author() ),
                get_the_author()
            );
        ?>
```

Any help understanding what how this code block is working would be great. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The % signs are arguments in the string to be formatted. The s represents a string type argument must be passed. I've notated which arguments are connected to which strings being passed in.

```
get_permalink() - %1 string type
get_the_date( 'c' ) - %2 string type
get_the_date() - %3 string type
get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) %4 string type
sprintf( esc_attr(__( 'View all posts by %s', 'toolbox' ), get_the_author() ) %5 string type (Also %s refers to get_the_author())
get_the_author() - %6 string type
```

For more information see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php